# Why can't I upload my local image with angular-cli?

Tags: html, css, angular, angular-cli

Everything works great on localhost but when I publish the app on github the image wont load. I've the picture inside src/resources. Have also tried to put it inside the public folder. Using angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.9

```
background:
          linear-gradient(
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5), 
          rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5)), url(../../recources/cinema-min-600.jpg);
```

Comment: Can you show your directory structure?  Does your image show up in a build?  What do you mean by publishing to github?

Answer (score 0):

You miss spelled `resources` in your link.

Try to change

`url(../../recources/cinema-min-600.jpg);`

to

`url(../../resources/cinema-min-600.jpg);`

Comment: Had miss spelled the folder to so it should work. I use the angular-cli if that can be something with that, because I can now see that it wont get exported to github